# Доступ к переменной из другого класса

Tags: java

Уже битую неделю я пытаюсь заставить мой код достать `recievedData` из `ServerThread` и отправить его в `Main`, чтобы потом записать его в `JTextArea`.
Пробовал и геттеры, и сеттеры, но к результату это меня не привело.

**Main.java**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class Main extends ServerThread {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        JFrame main_frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel main_panel = new JPanel();

        main_frame.setSize(600,500);
        main_frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        main_frame.setTitle("MessageBox");
        main_frame.add(main_panel);

        main_panel.setLayout(null); 

        JButton send_button = new JButton("Send");
        send_button.setBounds(480,360,80,25);
        main_panel.add(send_button);

        JButton menu = new JButton("Menu");
        menu.setBounds(480,390,80,25);

        JFrame frame_menu = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel_menu = new JPanel();

        main_panel.add(menu);

        frame_menu.setSize(400,400);
        frame_menu.setTitle("Menu");
        frame_menu.add(panel_menu);

        panel_menu.setLayout(null);

        JTextField TX_port = new JTextField(5);
        TX_port.setBounds(20,20,45,20);
        panel_menu.add(TX_port);

        JLabel TX = new JLabel("TX:");
        TX.setBounds(1,20,45,20);
        panel_menu.add(TX);


        JTextField RX_port = new JTextField(5);
        RX_port.setBounds(20,50,45,20);
        panel_menu.add(RX_port);


        JLabel RX = new JLabel("RX:");
        RX.setBounds(1,50,45,20);
        panel_menu.add(RX);


        JTextField send_text_field = new JTextField(30);
        send_text_field.setBounds(20,360,450,25);
        main_panel.add(send_text_field);

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        main_panel.add(textArea);

        JScrollPane textAreaPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        textAreaPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        textAreaPane.setBounds(20,20,540,325);
        main_panel.add(textAreaPane);

        /*
        Вот тут мне нужно получить доступ к переменной recievedData.
         */

        send_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                 String sended_data=send_text_field.getText();
                 String sum = "TX: " + sended_data;
                 textArea.append(sum + "\n");
                 send_text_field.setText("");


                }
            });

        menu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                frame_menu.setVisible(true);
                frame_menu.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            }
        });

        main_frame.setVisible(true);
        main_frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

}
```

**SocketThread.java ---->ServerThread**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

class ServerThread extends Thread

{
    ServerSocket ss = null;
    Socket s = null;

    public ServerThread(ServerSocket sSocket)
    {
        ss = sSocket;
    }


    public void run()
    {
        InputStream is;
        OutputStream os;

        try
        {
            s = ss.accept();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            stop();
        }

        System.out.println("Connected.");

        try
        {
            is = s.getInputStream();
            os = s.getOutputStream();

            while(true)
            {
                String recievedData = recvString(is);
                sendString(os, recievedData);
                os.flush();
              /*
               Отсюда нужно достать recievedData
              */

                System.out.println(recievedData); 

                if(recievedData.equals("quit"))
                    break;
            }

            is.close();
            os.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            stop();
        }

        try
        {
            s.close();
            ss.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            stop();
        }
    }

    static void sendString(OutputStream os,
                           String s)
            throws IOException
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            os.write((byte)s.charAt(i));
        }
        os.write('\n');
        os.flush();
    }

    static String recvString(InputStream is)
            throws IOException
    {
        String szBuf = "";
        int ch = is.read();

        while (ch >= 0 && ch != '\n')
        {
            szBuf += (char)ch;
            ch = is.read();
        }
        return szBuf;
    }
}
```

**SocketServer**

```
import java.net.*;

public class SocketServer
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(
                "* Socket Server *");

        ServerSocket ss = null;
        try
        {
            ss = new ServerSocket(9998);  
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            System.exit(0);
        }

        int nPort = ss.getLocalPort();

        System.out.println(
                "Local Port: " + nPort);

        ServerThread sThread = null;

        sThread = new ServerThread(ss);
        sThread.start();

        System.out.println(
                "Waiting connection...");

        try
        {
            sThread.join();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }

        try
        {
            ss.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

**SocketClient**

```
package com.ooo;

import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import com.ooo.Main.*;


public class SocketClient{

    public static void main(String args[]){


        System.out.println(
                "* Socket Client *");

        Socket s = null;


        try
        {
            s = new Socket("localhost", 9999); 
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            System.exit(0);
        }

        int nPort = s.getLocalPort();
        System.out.println("Local Port: " + nPort);

        InputStream is;
        OutputStream os;

        try
        {
            is = s.getInputStream();
            os = s.getOutputStream();

            String transievingData;
            while(true)
            {
                transievingData = getKbdString();

                sendString(os, transievingData);
                os.flush();
                if(transievingData.equals("quit"))
                    break;

                transievingData = recvString(is);

                System.out.println(transievingData); 
            }

            is.close();
            os.close();
            s.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }

    static void sendString(OutputStream os,
                           String s)
            throws IOException
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            os.write((byte)s.charAt(i));
        }
        os.write('\n');
        os.flush();
    }

    static String recvString(InputStream is)
            throws IOException
    {
        String szBuf = "";
        int ch = is.read();

        while (ch >= 0 && ch != '\n')
        {
            szBuf += (char)ch;
            ch = is.read();
        }
        return szBuf;
    }

    static public String getKbdString()
    {
        byte bKbd[] = new byte[256];
        int iCnt = 0;
        String szStr = "";

        try
        {
            iCnt = System.in.read(bKbd);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }

        szStr = new String(bKbd, 0, iCnt);
        szStr = szStr.trim();
        return szStr;
    }
}
```

**Run**

```
package com.ooo;

class Run {

    public static void main(final String ... args) throws InterruptedException {

        Thread one = new Thread(() -> SocketServer.main(args));
        Thread two = new Thread(() -> SocketClient.main(args));

        one.start();
        two.start();

        one.join();
        two.join();
    }

}
```

Comment: Чтобы получить доступ к переменной, она должна быть как минимум полем какого-либо класса. Но ни как не локальной переменной метода, цикла и пр.
Либо можно передать данные с помощью callback-ов. Это типа листенеров.
И что-то не заметно, чтобы Ваш треад запускался в работу. Следовательно за его переменными следить бесполезно:)

Comment: Потоки создаются в своей независимой памяти, поэтому они не имеют доступа к переменным другого класса, который является другим потоком. Для того чтобы передавать данные между потоками нужно создать сервис, который будет вызываться независимо от каждого потока и через него передать требуемые данные. Имплементации этого сервиса не обязательно делать через сокет, например можно использовать буффер, или файл, в худшем случае  можно воспользоваться другим сервисом и протоколом обмена. В вашем коде ничего не передается и ничего не принимается, поэтому вы не можете использовать геттеры и сеттеры.

Comment: @Sergey , SocketThread.java ---->ServerThread это продолжение SocketServer, его код я добавил в вопрос.

Comment: Ясно. Чтобы решить поставленный вопрос, надо сначала решить другие проблемы с Вашей программой или двумя программами. Вообще очень смутно видится, что Вы хотите получить. Main - это графическая оболочка к серверу? Или это графический клиент сервера? Зачем вообще `Main extends ServerThread`? extends он может и extends, но никаким образом не связан с реально работающим экземпляром ServerThread, чтобы получать из него данные тем или иным образом.

Comment: @Sergey , extends - это ещё одна попытка получить данные из переменной =) Сама программа -это p2p связь. Main создаёт графический интерфейс для общения. В то же время запускается SocketServer и SocketClient.

Comment: @ZuchoK Таким образом у Вас есть сервер для общения. А Main - это клиент? И Вы хотите получать сообщения с сервера? Если это так, то Вам не нужен доступ к переменным ServerThread. Вы должны подключить Main к серверу через Socket и получать сообщения из этого сокета. Ваш прожект требует тщательной переработки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Сначала запустить `RunServer`, а затем `RunClient`

**Main**

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main {

    public static String t = "test";
    public static String sendtext = "";
    public static String text = "";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        JFrame main_frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel main_panel = new JPanel();

        main_frame.setSize(600,500);
        main_frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        main_frame.setTitle("MessageBox");
        main_frame.add(main_panel);

        main_panel.setLayout(null); 

        JButton send_button = new JButton("Send");
        send_button.setBounds(480,360,80,25);
        main_panel.add(send_button);

        JButton menu = new JButton("Menu");
        menu.setBounds(480,390,80,25);

        JFrame frame_menu = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel_menu = new JPanel();

        main_panel.add(menu);

        frame_menu.setSize(400,400);
        frame_menu.setTitle("Menu");
        frame_menu.add(panel_menu);

        panel_menu.setLayout(null);

        JTextField TX_port = new JTextField(5);
        TX_port.setBounds(20,20,45,20);
        panel_menu.add(TX_port);

        JLabel TX = new JLabel("TX:");
        TX.setBounds(1,20,45,20);
        panel_menu.add(TX);


        JTextField RX_port = new JTextField(5);
        RX_port.setBounds(20,50,45,20);
        panel_menu.add(RX_port);


        JLabel RX = new JLabel("RX:");
        RX.setBounds(1,50,45,20);
        panel_menu.add(RX);


        JTextField send_text_field = new JTextField(30);
        send_text_field.setBounds(20,360,450,25);
        main_panel.add(send_text_field);

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setFont(new Font(textArea.getFont().getFamily(), Font.BOLD, 15));
        main_panel.add(textArea);

        JScrollPane textAreaPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        textAreaPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        textAreaPane.setBounds(20,20,540,325);
        main_panel.add(textAreaPane);

        Thread update = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                    if(!textArea.getText().equals(text))
                        textArea.setText(text);
                    send_button.setEnabled(!send_text_field.getText().isEmpty());
                }
            };
        };
        update.start();

        send_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                sendtext = send_text_field.getText();
                send_text_field.setText("");
            }
        });

        menu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                frame_menu.setVisible(true);
                frame_menu.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            }
        });

        main_frame.setVisible(true);
        main_frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

}
```

**RunClient**

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class RunClient {

    public static void main(final String ... args) throws InterruptedException {
        
        System.err.println("Frame: ");
        Thread frame = new Thread(() -> Main.main(null));
        frame.start();
        
        
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Username:");
        if(input == null || input.isEmpty())
            input = "User_" + System.nanoTime();
        final String name = input;
        System.err.println("SocketClient: ");
        Thread two = new Thread(() -> SocketClient.main(name));
        two.start();
        two.join();
    }

}
```

**RunServer**

```
public class RunServer {

    public static void main(final String ... args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.err.println("Frame: ");
        Thread frame = new Thread(() -> Main.main(null));
        frame.start();
        
        Thread one = new Thread(() -> SocketServer.main(args));
        one.start();
        one.join();
    }

}
```

**ServerThread**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

class ServerThread extends Thread {

    public static String username = "";
    public static String text = "";
    public static String sendtext = "Test";
    
    ServerSocket ss = null;
    Socket s = null;

    public ServerThread(ServerSocket sSocket)  {
        ss = sSocket;
    }


    public void run()  {
        InputStream is;
        OutputStream os;

        try {
            s = ss.accept();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            stop();
        }

        System.out.println("Connected.");

        try {
            is = s.getInputStream();
            os = s.getOutputStream();

            String transievingData;
            while(true) {
                sendtext = "<Server> " + Main.sendtext;
                if(Main.sendtext.isEmpty())
                    sendtext = "";
                if(Main.sendtext.equals("quit"))
                    break;
                Main.sendtext = "";
                if(!sendtext.isEmpty()) {
                    System.err.println(sendtext); 
                    Main.text += sendtext + "\n";
                }
                transievingData = sendtext;
                sendString(os, transievingData);
                os.flush();

                transievingData = recvString(is);

                if(!transievingData.isEmpty())
                Main.text += transievingData + "\n";
                if(!transievingData.isEmpty())
                    System.out.println(transievingData); 
                sendtext = "";
//              sendtext =  Main.sendtext;
//              Main.sendtext = "";
//              
//              String recievedData = recvString(is);
//                Main.text += recievedData + "\n";
//                sendString(os, recievedData);
//                os.flush();
//              /*
//               Отсюда нужно достать recievedData
//              */
//
//                System.out.println(recievedData); 
//
//                if(recievedData.equals("quit"))
//                    break;
            }

            is.close();
            os.close();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            stop();
        }

        try {
            s.close();
            ss.close();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            stop();
        }
    }

    static void sendString(OutputStream os, String s) throws IOException {
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            os.write((byte)s.charAt(i));
        }
        os.write('\n');
        os.flush();
    }

    static String recvString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        String szBuf = "";
        int ch = is.read();

        while (ch >= 0 && ch != '\n') {
            szBuf += (char)ch;
            ch = is.read();
        }
        return szBuf;
    }
}
```

**SocketClient**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;


public class SocketClient {

    public static String username = "";
    public static String text = "";
    public static String sendtext = "Test";
    
    public static void main(String username) {
        SocketClient.username = username;
        
        System.out.println("* Socket Client *");

        Socket s = null;

        try {
            s = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 4040); 
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        int nPort = s.getLocalPort();
        System.out.println("Local Port: " + nPort);

        InputStream is;
        OutputStream os;

        try {
            is = s.getInputStream();
            os = s.getOutputStream();

            sendString(os, username + " is join");
            
            String transievingData;
            while(true) {
                sendtext = username + ": " + Main.sendtext;
                if(Main.sendtext.isEmpty())
                    sendtext = "";
                if(Main.sendtext.equals("quit")) {
                    sendString(os, username + " left server");
                    os.flush();
                    break;
                }
                Main.sendtext = "";
                if(!sendtext.isEmpty()) {
                    Main.text += sendtext + "\n";
                }
                transievingData = getKbdString();
                sendString(os, transievingData);
                os.flush();

                transievingData = recvString(is);

                if(!transievingData.isEmpty())
                Main.text += transievingData + "\n";
                if(!transievingData.isEmpty())
                    System.out.println(transievingData); 
                sendtext = "";
//              transievingData = getKbdString();
//              if(!sendtext.isEmpty()) {
//                  System.out.println(sendtext);
//                  if(sendtext.toUpperCase().equals("EXIT")) {
//                      sendString(os, "Client left server");
//                      break;
//                  }
//                  sendString(os, sendtext);
//                  sendtext = "";
////                    os.flush();
//              }
//
//              transievingData = recvString(is);
//
            }

            is.close();
            os.close();
            s.close();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

    static void sendString(OutputStream os, String s) throws IOException {
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            os.write((byte)s.charAt(i));
        }
        os.write('\n');
        os.flush();
    }

    static String recvString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        String szBuf = "";
        int ch = is.read();

        while (ch >= 0 && ch != '\n') {
            szBuf += (char)ch;
            ch = is.read();
        }
        return szBuf;
    }

    static public String getKbdString() {
//      byte bKbd[] = new byte[256];
//      int iCnt = 0;
//      String szStr = "";
//
//      try {
//          iCnt = System.in.read(bKbd);
//      } catch(Exception ex) {
//          System.out.println(ex.toString());
//      }
//
//      szStr = new String(bKbd, 0, iCnt);
//      szStr = szStr.trim();
        return sendtext;
    }
}
```

**SocketServer**

```
import java.net.*;

public class SocketServer {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("* Socket Server *");

        ServerSocket ss = null;
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(4040);  
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        int nPort = ss.getLocalPort();

        System.out.println("Local Port: " + nPort);

        ServerThread sThread = null;

        sThread = new ServerThread(ss);
        sThread.start();

        System.out.println("Waiting connection...");

        try {
            sThread.join();
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            ss.close();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Проект:

```
src:
> Main.java
> RunClient.java
> RunServer.java
> ServerThread.java
> SocketClient.java
> SocketServer.java
```

Comment: А в Main.java ничего редактировать не надо?

Comment: Ну я геттер сделал, думаю дальше Вы сами сможете.  Если нет, то подскажу:
где-нибудь у вас в коде должно быть где-то `ServerThread server = new ServerThread(sSocket);` и затем вызывать геттер: ` server.getRecievedData();` или в `SocketThread.java ----> ServerThread` сделать `myRecievedData` и  `getRecievedData()` статичными

Comment: статичные вызывать так: `ServerThread.getRecievedData()`

Comment: Чёт я до сих пор не понимаю как из этого сеттера достать String.....

Comment: я добавил это в свой ответ (ServerThread.java так же был изменен в ответе)

Comment: И еще: у Вас `Main.java` ни чем не связан с другими классами. В своем вопросе Вы не весь код показали (я не могу понять каким образом Вы пытаетесь подключится к серверу)

Comment: Я не добавлял весь код лишь по той причине, что мне нужно лишь **узнать самый лёгкий и простой способ, как достать переменную из одного класса и отправить в другой**, дальше я сам по аналогии попытаюсь сделать. Да и `Main.java` - лишь интерфейс, в который должны приходить и уходить данные, не больше. Я сейчас ещё добавлю два класса, которые у меня есть.

Comment: тогда лучше вариант без static

Comment: добавил 2 вариант в свой ответ

Comment: код `SocketClient.java` я добавил уже.

Comment: Теперь я связал `Main` с `SocketServer` и `SocketClient` (теперь это вполне рабочее приложение), просто скопируйте код (лучше в новый проект)

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, Вам необходимо подключится к серверу, передать ему сообщение и принять ответное. Делается это через Socket.
Странно, что догадались сделать сервер, а клиент не смогли. Обычно всё наоборот происходит.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    
        // подключиться к серверу
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 9998); // заменить на реальные адрес и порт
        // out для передачи 
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        // in для приёма
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        ...
 
        send_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                 String sended_data = send_text_field.getText();
                 // передать сообщение на сервер
                 out.println(sended_data);
                 // принять сообщение с сервера
                 String received_data = in.readLine();
                 String sum = "TX: " + sended_data + '\n' +
                              "RX: " + received_data;   
                 textArea.append(sum + "\n");
                 send_text_field.setText("");
            }
        });
        ...

    }

}
```

Comment: На самом деле у меня есть класс SocketClient. Но мне нужно лишь узнать метод изъятия переменных из других классов, а дальше я сам по аналогии сделаю в клиенте.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле Вы предлагаете совершенно бредовую ситуацию сразу по нескольким аспектам, что правильно ответить просто не возможно.
Но тем не менее.
Самый простой способ.
Вы должны определить поле класса, в котором будет хранится сообщение. И использовать его вместо переменной. Тогда эти данные можно будет извлечь из класса.

```
class ServerThread extends Thread {
    ServerSocket ss = null;
    Socket s = null;
    String receivedData;

    ...

    public String getReceivedData() {
        return receivedData();
    }

    ...
    public void run() {
        ...
        while(true) {
            recievedData = recvString(is);
            sendString(os, recievedData);
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Теперь можете смотреть, что там принимается.

```
String rd = sThread.getReceivedData();
```

или

```
String rd = sThread.receivedData;
```

В зависимости от того, сделаете геттер для поля или объявите поле доступным (public например)

Но там, где Вы обозначили своё желание получить эти данные - это просто полный бред.
Ничего Вы там никогда не получите и будите мучать форум дурацким вопросом, извините.

Минус, если что, не мой

Comment: Я, от силы, программирую неделю. Я не могу правильно выразить свою мысль сразу. Да и сам вопрос заключается в том, что мне нужно получить данные именно в том месте, где я обозначил. Иначе их записать в `JTextArea` будет нереально (ну я так думаю).

Comment: Ну это же азы не то что java, а ооп вообще. Как данные хранятся и извлекаются из классов. И начинать тогда уж следует с простых вещей. Сетевые программы сложны для начала,

Comment: В этом и дело, не успел я ещё досконально изучить весь синтаксис java, про ООП я вообще молчу. Я очень долго искал информацию по этому вопросу, прежде чем его задать, но, какой бы то ни был способ, он у меня просто не работает. Возможно я придумал слишком сложный проект, не исключаю, но раз начал, нужно и закончить.

Comment: Я же Вам говорю, что в рамках такого прожекта этот бред не имеет решения. В Main не возможно получить вообще ничего из ServerThread напрямую в принципе. Только через Socket.

Comment: Ладно. Если эта задача не имеет решений, значит прийдётся её оставить. В любом случае спасибо за попытку объяснить мне это.